# How can I select a string from between specified words

Tags: c#

I Have a string `"User " + nick + " has been connected"` (WinForms)

Can you please tell me, how to get nick from that string ? (it will be printed as 1 string)

It's behind "User" and "has" words.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use nick? :D

Comment: Are you really given only this string?  There's probably a simple way of passing the variable value around.  For example, a control's `.Tag` property.

Comment: because its chat application, i know that i can send it, but i need put it out of complete string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex with `^User (.*?) has been connected$`

```
var myUser = Regex.Match(inputString, "^User (.*?) has been connected$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Throw in a .Value in there and you'll get the name as a string... Your code returns a System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group

Comment: well a `Group` implements ToString() so it works, but sure

Comment: Yes it does... So your Point is to call the .ToString() -method instead of the .Value property? It is still not implicitly converted to a string...

Comment: There, I added the `.Value` :)

Answer (score 1):

This could do:

```
string nickname = yourString.Replace("User ", "").Replace(" has been connected", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The boilerplate text is constant so read past the 5 characters of `"user "` upto the length of the string less the length of the characters you always know will be there.

```
string name = text.Substring(5, text.Length - 24);
```